# Publish action types error

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph

I define my action type on facebook using open graph. After creating the action when I want to submit the action it creates the error. It says "You must publish at least one action to your Timeline using this action type.".

I am using PHP code to publish it on Facebook

```
$result1 = $facebookObj->api('/me/my_ns:read','post',"read:'http://www.google.com'");
```

But it gives access token error.

I am not sure what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the action object pair to post like below, you may try:

```
$facebookObj->api('me/my_ns:read','post',array("read"=>"http://www.google.com","access_token"=>"$your_access_token"));
```